# Android: Automatically modify metadata of any new file(s) saved or downloaded

Tags: java, android, kotlin, operating-system

Is there a way to attach a piece of custom code to the Android OS which automatically deletes all the metadata of any new file(s) saved or downloaded (e.x. owner, last updated by, creation date, etc.)?

Comment: There is no "system call" that is unique to downloading files.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any way to attach a piece of code which automatically modifies the metadata of any file being downloaded?

Comment: The OS doesn't know a file was downloaded-  downloading isn't done by the OS.  The OS sees network data being sent, and then a file being saved.  It doesn't know the two are related.  I'm also curious what metadata you want changed, because the Linux filesystem really doesn't have much.  Just timestamps and owner/group owner.

Comment: @GabeSechan I would like to remove all the metadata for any file (whether that is the owner/group owner or the timestamp).

Comment: Not possible.  Those are required fields for linux to work.  All files have an mtime, ctime, atime, and an owner account/group.  In android, the owning account/group will be the app that saves, since the security system has one userid per app.  They have no relationship to where the file came from or when it was made on the server, just to when it was saved to disk locally

Comment: @GabeSechan Do you know what types of files I can remove metadata from as well as what metadata I can remove from those types of files?

Comment: Linux (and thus Android) don't really store metadata.  Just creation time, access time, and modified time (and its possible those may not be accurate, depending on filesystem).  And the user/group that owns the file.  None of those may be removed.  Any other metadata isn't handled by the OS, its part of the file.  To change that, you'd need to know the file format and edit the file.